# ASP.NET 5 and RazorEngine - Unit test works but web API fails

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, razorengine, .net-4.6

I have a Web API project that I've created in ASP.NET 5. The Web API uses RazorEngine (v3.7.0) to parse templates.

The parsing logic is inside of a class library. It is this class library that does the actual parsing. The web API invokes this class library. The name of the class that has the parsing logic is TemplateParser and the method that parses the template is named Parse().

I have a unit test project to call TemplateParser.Parse(). This unit test works fine.

However, when I invoke the same method by calling the Web API, I get the error mentioned below. The error is that it fails to find the System.Web.Razor assembly, version 3.0.0.0.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  FileName=System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

But then, why does the unit test work?

I am using VS 2015 Community Edition.

To debug, I run the web api project with F5 and then invoke the API from outside. I use the "Web" option for my web server (right now, I am not using IIS express).

I am using the dnx46 version of the framework in both the web api and class library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your dependencies in your project.json file in the project giving you the error:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor":  "6.0.0-beta5" //or whichever version you want
```

Edit:

```
//inside of 
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
         routes.MapRoute(
         name: "default",
         template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor is not available.  But there is a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Razor already.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an ASP.NET 5 project? If you are then it will be available.

Comment: Okay, I tested again by creating a new ASP.NET 5 project from scratch. This time, I did see Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor, and included it.

To make it as simple as possible, I added the RazorEngine template processing code directly in the API.

But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Do you have your application setup to use MVC in your Startup.cs file?

Comment: Yes, startup.cs has been setup to use MVC.

Comment: In your project are there any reference errors shown (a little caution icon on the references in solution explorer)? What I've found with asp.net 5 projects is you can't reference a normal class library, it has to be a class library (package) project.

Comment: No, there aren't any reference errors with the caution icon. Could you please look at the github repo I mentioned above?

Comment: If you notice in your dependencies in project.json your TemplateManagement.Core has no version. It's because it is not compatible. Remove the project and add a new project with the same name but add it as a Class Library (Package) project type under 4.6 Your test project is an older class library as well which is why it works there.

Comment: You also have a warning that the TemplateService class you are using is obsolete. It suggests using RazorEngineService instead.

Comment: Actually, I did indeed add the TemplateManagement.Core project as a Class Library(Package). 

As for the test project, that isn't actually an older class library - I used the SideWaffle project template for XUnit.

But I did test again just now by changing the framework version to dnx46 in all the three projects - same error still.

And you're right about the TemplateService class. Will change that.